# Using Mailchimp RSS to Only Send Last Post

Tags: email, rss, mailchimp

I have a very simple RSS integration campaign set up for a tumblr blog to mailchimp. The idea is that there is a daily post on the tumblr blog that gets emailed out to a list by mailchimp. That email is set to go out at 12:00.

Sometimes, if a different campaign was used for some reason or there were other issues, mailchimp will try to send the campaign with the last 2 posts - one of which might have already been sent out.

How can I get mailchimp to send only the most recent post?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a FeedBlock and limit the items to only the first one.

```
*|FEEDBLOCK:https://www.url.com/test.xml|* *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=1]|*

*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*
*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT|*

*|END:FEEDITEMS|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

Answer (score 0):

Use RSSITEM family tags:

https://mailchimp.com/es/help/rss-merge-tags/

It will load the information of the last post.